# Give a Java local the same name as a method?

Tags: java

```
MyClassBuilder myClassBuilder = myClassBuilder()
```

A factory method to return a builder, assigned to a local of the same name as the method.

I've never seen this before today.  Does it make sense or should it be avoided?  It's not possible to meaningfully do this in Python or C++, so as I'm new to Java it feels wrong.  IntelliJ doesn't give so much as a warning and it results in some (to me) confusing looking code.

Put simply:  Is this considered idiomatic Java?

Edit:  I don't feel this is purely opinion based.  Major players in the Java community (possibly even the language creators themselves) may or may not be using this 'feature' of the language.  If they did it would indicate that it's idiomatic.  Answers would ideally cite references to where it's being used or specific problems that it solves.  I don't think this is a good language feature, I've never used it but I'm open-minded and prepared to be convinced otherwise.

Comment: It is possible in Python to set a variable to a function.... But anyway, there's nothing wrong with this since you know for sure one is a method and another is an instance variable

Comment: avoid, feels wrong to me too. usually these names are `of`, `builder`, etc

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is possible in both C++ and Python. I wouldn't call it "idiomatic" for Java, but it does make sense - it's a good name for both the factory method and the variable (arguably, `createClassBuilder()` would be a better name for the method).

Comment: The reason I say it's not possible in Python, is because you no longer have access to the original method.  Yes, it will run, but you can't use the method again, whereas in Java it appears you don't 'clobber' the method, it's still there in the namespace.  In C++ similar construct wouldn't compile for me, maybe there is a type for which it will.

Answer (score 1):

In java **method** and **field** names have their own name spaces, so they can be given the same name.

There are some code styles, that might use it:

```
public class Human {
    private String opinion;

    public Human opinion(String opinion) {
        this.opinion = opinion;
        return this;
    }

    public String opinion() {
        return opinion;
    }
```

Repetition due to field/method, field/parameter and method overloading.

Seen in fluent APIs, Builder patterns, from time to time getter-setter haters.

As you can see from the above it is kind of repetitive too. Verbal phrases for method names seems better (except we have `size()` and such).

Answer (score 0):

## Possible, but...

It is possible, and will compile, but it is really confusing. I think it is better to avoid such naming for your coworkers and/or your future self.

You can see [this website](https://dzone.com/articles/best-practices-variable-and) for good practices, and I think you can even find better, official sources.